# Tyepscript/es6 module exported by babel/webpack as _esModule with default property

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, babeljs

I've converted a javascript application into typescript, yet now that I've converted my code to typescript/es6-style exports, babel/webpack aren't exporting them correctly.

Since I now use the `export default...` syntax, babel turns it into an `esModule` object with the class actually attached to a `default` property.

Naturally, this object format is no longer valid for anyone actually using it.

I've tried adding the [babel-plugin-add-module-exports](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-add-module-exports) plugin to the mix but it hasn't changed anything. I'm wondering if typescript being in the mix has caused an issue.

.babelrc:

```
{
    "plugins": [
        "add-module-exports",
        "lodash"
    ]
}
```

tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2015",
    "module": "commonjs"
  }
}
```

webpack.config.js:

```
entry: {
    'myfile.ts'
},
output: {
    filename: 'myfile.js',
    library: 'MyApp',
    libraryTarget: 'umd'
},
resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.ts', '.js']
},
module: {
    loaders: [{
        test: /\.ts$/, loader: 'babel!ts-loader'
    }]
}
```

myfile.ts just exports a class:

```
export default class MyApp {...
```

Answer (score 0):

You could convert the bundle output to a [global variable](https://webpack.github.io/docs/library-and-externals.html). Currently `libraryTarget` points to UMD which supports [Commonjs](http://wiki.commonjs.org/wiki/CommonJS) and [AMD](https://github.com/amdjs/amdjs-api/wiki/AMD)